# Problem installing ruby 1.9.2 using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I get this error message when I rvm install 1.9.2

> Error running 'make ', please read /Users/danielreardon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log
>   There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

I'm very very new to all this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well what does this logfile say?

Comment: Thats my next problem - I can't actually find the log file!

Comment: Normally you should also see the same output that is written to the file on your Terminal while installing. Look for errors there and try to post as much information as possible. Otherwise we can't help!

Comment: And: `tail /Users/danielreardon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p136/make.log` does not output anything? Or is it telling you that there's no such file?

Comment: Possibly, to be honest I don't have any idea?

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, use RubyInstaller, that is my suggestion for beginners.

Comment: Doesn't seem like Windows judging from the file paths. @user605116, what exactly don't you understand? To install Ruby using RVM, you are in a Terminal. If you enter the command I posted above, what does it say?

Comment: He's on Mac OS. That's a Mac OS path to the user's home.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed [Apple's XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/xcode.html) development system? RVM requires that to install Ruby and many of the gems' native drivers. If not, download the latest version from Apple. Do NOT use the version on the Snow Leopard DVD because it's buggy.

Also, did you modify your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file according to the "post install" section in [RVM's installation page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)? SO many people forget that, but it's essential.

Also, before installing a Ruby via RVM, run `rvm notes` and make sure you've got all the prerequisites installed.